# Python cannot convert string to float to use when subtracting

Tags: python, selenium, beautifulsoup, floating-point, integer

I am trying to convert a string, "2,900.99", to a float. Trying `float(int("2,900.99"))` has not worked and `float("2,900.99")` is not working. The value is pulled from selenium and beautiful soup and the type of data is a string so I don't know how I can change the type of data. Thanks in advance for any answers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Get rid of any comma as it has no meaning for the number itself.

```py
float("2,900.99".replace(",", ""))
```

Results in `2900.99`

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove the commas first, like this:

```
float("2,900.99".replace(",",""))
```

returns `2900.99`

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove the `,` by replacing it with nothing and then to convert the string to float.

```py
float("2,900.99".replace(',',''))
```